# Find the closed form for the generating fuction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form, formal-power-series

I am given $g_0 = g_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $g_n + (n+1)g_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n!}$ where $n\geq2$.

I need to find the closed form for the generating function $g(z)$ and the closed form for $g_n$.

I'm not sure how to do this.

I multiplied both sides of the recurrence by $z^n$ and summed over all $n\geq0$. I know $\sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)g_{n+1}z^n= Dg(z)$ and $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{z^n}{n!} = e^z$. Which gives the equation $$g(z) + Dg(z) = e^z$$ Do I treat this as a first order differential equation?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Differential equation $g'+g=e^z$ is pretty easy to solve by [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First-order_equation), you need the solution with $g(0)=\frac12$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Conifold.

Comment: Or one can solve the recursion directly as $[(n+1)!g_{n+1}]+[n!g_n]=1$ has solutions $g_n=a+b·(-1)^n$, with $a$ fixed by the equation.

Comment: How do you get the solution $g_n = a + b(-1)^n$

Comment: Assume arbitrary values for $g_0$ and $g_1$. Find explicitly the first few values $g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5$ and make a guess at the formula for $g_n$. It should be easy to find the generating function from there.

Comment: I think you meant $n \ge 1$ for the recurrence relation.  Otherwise you need another initial condition to be able to compute $g_2$.

Comment: That should have been $n!g_n=a+b(-1)^n$, using characteristic polynomial and "intelligent guessing" (method of undetermined coefficients), leading to $a=\frac12$, $b=0$, $g_n=\frac1{2n!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$n! g_n + (n+1)! g_{n+1} = 1,$$
which suggests letting $h_n = n! g_n$ and solving
$$h_n + h_{n+1} = 1 \quad \text{for $n\ge 1$}$$ with initial conditions $h_0=0!g_0=1/2$ and $h_1=1!g_1=1/2$.  Let $H(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n z^n$ be the generating function for $h_n$.  The recurrence relation implies that
$$\sum_{n \ge 1} h_n z^n + \sum_{n \ge 1} h_{n+1} z^n = \sum_{n \ge 1} z^n.$$
Equivalently,
$$H(z) - h_0 + \frac{1}{z} (H(z) - h_0 - h_1 z) = \frac{z}{1-z},$$
which implies that
$$H(z) = \frac{1/2}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} z^n,$$
so $h_n = 1/2$ for $n \ge 0$.  (You could also have deduced this directly from the recurrence $h_{n+1}=1-h_n$ and initial condition $h_0=1/2$, without using a generating function.) Hence $$g_n = \frac{h_n}{n!} = \frac{1/2}{n!}$$ for $n \ge 0$.